# Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location returns the "wrong" value

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I try to use the code below on Monodroid, but "path" is always an empty string.
The interesting thing is that it has already worked, and I don't know what has changed.
The "writeline" below is just for testing purposes, it produces: ": MyDLL.dll: : ".

Last week I updated to `mono-android-4.2.7.15330979`, but it also worked there.

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
System.Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}: {3}", path, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType()).Location));
```

Did I make a mistake?

Is there any known problem with this Assembly functions in mono-android?

**EDIT :** I also tried this command in std c# in a console application, there it worked!

I found out that the command works, if the project option "Use Fast Deployment(debug mode only)" is enabled. Could this become a problem, when the app is distributed, or built as release?

Comment: I tried it in std C# and the path is not empty, could be a mono thing.

Comment: I know, I forgot to mention it before. I also tried it in std C#.